# split 00:00:00 to be 00:00 in JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl

how can i use fn:split or fn:join to get 00:00 from 00:00:00? I have certain steps as following:

```
         <c:set var="datetime" value="${row.starttime}"></c:set>
         <c:set var="times" value="${fn:split(datetime,' ')}"></c:set>
         <c:set var="time" value="${fn:split(times[1],':')}"></c:set>
```

I got datetime value from sql query result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `row.starttime` is a `java.util.Date`, you can use [formatDate](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_format_formatdate_tag.htm) to get 00:00 (hours and minutes, i assume) like this:

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${date}" pattern="kk:mm" />
```

if row.starttime is a String you could use substring to get the first five characters:

```
${fn:substring("00:00:00", 0, 5)}
```

the second solution assumes the format is always `hh:mm:ss` (f.e. 06:32:00 and not 6:32:0)